# django rest: testing file upload but request.data is empty

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I try to test file upload with django rest framework, but the `request.data` is empty

test:

```
def test_update_story_cover(self):
    auth_token, story_id = self.create_story()
    image_path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'book.jpg')
    url = reverse('story_modify', kwargs={'pk': story_id})

    with open(image_path) as cover:
        response = self.client.patch(
            url, data={'cover': cover, 'title': 'test title'},
            content_type='multipart/form-data',
            HTTP_AUTHORIZATION=auth_token)

    self.assertEqual(response.status_code, status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

view:

```
class StoryModifyView(RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):
    ...

    def update(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        print(request.data)
        print(request.FILES)
        print(request.body)
        ...
```

the output is

```
<QueryDict: {}> {}
<MultiValueDict: {}>
b"{'cover': <_io.TextIOWrapper name='/some-path/stories/tests/test_stories/books.jpg' mode='r' encoding='UTF-8'>, 'title': 'test title'}"
```

the real frontend can successfully upload image, and the `request.data` is not empty, so I guess there is something wrong in the test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work

```
from rest_framework.test import APIClient

def test_update_story_cover(self):
    client = APIClient()        

    auth_token, story_id = self.create_story()
    image_path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'book.jpg')
    url = reverse('story_modify', kwargs={'pk': story_id})

    with open(image_path, 'rb') as cover:
        response = client.patch(
            path=url, data={'cover': cover, 'title': 'test title'},
            format='multipart',
            HTTP_AUTHORIZATION=auth_token)

    self.assertEqual(response.status_code, status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

Comment: I tried this and staus_code will return 415, the return data is `{'detail': 'Unsupported media type "application/octet-stream" in request.'}`

Comment: Ok I was trying with post and it works fine. It do have problems with patch. What you can do is use `APIClient` provided by rest framework and it should work fine. See my edit.